# Mock HttpClient with many endpoints and large responses

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, httpclient, moq

I mock the `SendAsync` method of `HttpClient` using the following code:

```cs
var mock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();

Parallel.ForEach(endpoints, (e) =>
{
    mock
    .Protected()
    .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
        "SendAsync",
        ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(
            x => x.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Contains(e.Endpoint)),
        ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    .ReturnsAsync(() => new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        Content = e.Response
    });
});

var client = new HttpClient(mock.Object);
```

where `endpoints` is a list of objects of the following type:

```
class Parameters
{
    public string Endpoint { get; }

    private readonly string _response;
    public StringContent Response
    {
        get { return new StringContent(_response); }
    }
}
```

This mocking approach works as expected, with one caveat. The speed of mocking the protected endpoint drops significantly having added a decent number of endpoints. I need to mock the client for ~5000 endpoints each with ~2MB response. (Designing tests for fewer endpoints and smaller data seems great, but, unfortunately, not an option in my use case). The mocking speed drops significantly having added ~2k endpoints. After ~2h of runtime, it was not able to reach ~3k endpoint.

I am wondering if there is an alternative/better approach of mocking `HttpClient` ideally with linear asymptotic behavior.

Comment: Are all 2MB responses identical? Do you reuse the string using for `_response`? Did you make sure it is slow at the handler part and not string-generating part?

Comment: `Response` needs to be a new instance based on `_response` at every API request to the endpoint, so `_response` is reused for different calls to an endpoint. I have not done CPU profiling, so cannot tell for sure if it is getting increasingly slower at the handler or string generation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to eliminate Mock overhead by overriding HttpMessageHandler?

Other potential bottleneck is a Mock<> code which match request URL and endpoint's response. With large number of endpoints it does make sense to optimize that (e.g. MockHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync() to use Dictionary or Lookup to find response).

```
public class MockHttpMessageHandler : HttpMessageHandler
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, HttpContent> _endpoints;

    public MockHttpMessageHandler(Dictionary<string, HttpContent> endpoints)
    {
        _endpoints = endpoints;
    }
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (_endpoints.TryGetValue(request.RequestUri.ToString(), out var content))
            return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage() { Content = content });

        return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage() { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound });
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a good suggestion, though I'm not sure how you could use that to mock the endpoint.